# No ClassTag Avaliable for Trait / Abstract Class

Tags: java, scala, reflection

Consider the following trait:

```scala
trait Aggregatable[Command] {

  protected[aggregator] type ActorReply

  protected[aggregator] val actorReplyClassTag: ClassTag[ActorReply]

  ... // Additional Implementation 
}
```

then, the following abstract class:

```scala
abstract class AsyncWorker[Request, Reply] extends Aggregatable[AsyncWorkerRequest[Request, Reply]] {

  override final type ActorReply = AsyncWorkerReply[Request, Reply]

  override protected val actorReplyClassTag: ClassTag[AsyncWorkerReply[Request, Reply]] = ???

  ... // Additional Implementation 
}
```

and then the concrete implementation:

```scala
class SiteCategoriesExtractorWorker extends AsyncWorker[SiteCategoriesRequest, SiteCategoriesReply]
```

The problem is that I cannot initialize actorReplyClassTag properly.

The desired solution should:

1. SiteCategoriesExtractorWorker should not be aware of actorReplyClassTag
2. type ActorReply is used on `aggregator` package as `asInstanceOf[ActorReply]`
3. actorReplyClassTag is used on `messageAdapter` (https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl/ActorContext.html#messageAdapter(scala.Function1,scala.reflect.ClassTag)
4. Aggregatable is preferred to be a trait rather then abstract class

**Note:** I'm using reflection in order to make some generic aggregation over Aggregatable interface.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass class tags of the parameters down to `AsyncWorker`, then class tag will be available implicitly:

```
class AsyncWorker[Request : ClassTag, Reply : ClassTag] extends Aggregatable[AsyncWorkerRequest[Request, Reply]] {
  type ActorReply = AsyncWorkerReply[Request, Reply]
  val actorReplyClassTag: ClassTag[ActorReply] = implicitly[ClassTag[ActorReply]]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Its Indeed compiled, looks like its not solved the issue unfortunately, the problem is that `messageAdaper` not working as expected, since `AsyncWorker[T1,U1]` is equals to `AsyncWorker[T2,T2]` on runtime.

Comment: ```context.messageAdapter[aggregatable.ActorReply](reply => WrappedReply(aggregatable.aggregatableId, reply))(aggregatable.actorReplyClassTag)
```

Comment: ```private case class WrappedReply(aggregatableId: String, reply: Any) extends AggregatorCommand```

Comment: Well, yeah, that's type erasure. ClassTag does not capture erased types, you need a TypeTag for that.

Comment: Got it. Is it possible to both provide TypeTag and ClassTag? since `messageAdapter` require ClassTag but I want to distinguish between `AsyncWorker[T1,U1]` and `AsyncWorker[T2,T2]`?

Comment: Well, depends on what specifically you mean by "distinguish". Perhaps, just make parameter class tags available separately, rather than the reply's?

Comment: Actually its wasn't TypeTag Issue. Its was Akka messageAdapter Issue which cannot be unique to each request. I wasn't aware about it - I'm thinking of a way to send a request and to pass it with some `id` in order to have WrappedReply with this `id` and then I can handle messages this way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368454/akka-typed-context-messageadapter-does-not-manage-responses-correctly

Comment: Update: Since messageAdapter not supporting adding `id`, I changed the way to Ask Pattern, then I can map the requests to the replies handling.